# How to get back logcat before dolphin version on android studio?

Tags: android-studio, logcat

The logcat change on the version Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1

In my little screen this new logcat is not adapted at all.

How can keep the old one ?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

To manage wich version of logcat use :

`Settings` > `Experimental` >
Don't check the `Enable new Logcat tool window` at the end.

[image]

Comment: But what is wrong with Google, The only pro is the coloring of the logs according to level the rest are cons, before we would filter by simply selecting from a dropdown now we have to write regex just to filter logs, shame on you

Comment: Guys I can't even copy a json response from the server :/ . I know I should get the json response from somewhere else like postman, but I had to do this step for debugging a specific edge case. Google be like: Nah, you are not going to copy that logcat.

Comment: @m'hdsemps yes I really hate the new logcat! Such a stupid move.

Comment: new logcat is awfull !!! I cannot even see a simple log with this package:app level:debug -tag:MyTestTag  , imaginate if I need something quick .... shame

Comment: After the update to Electric Eel the checkmark is **back on** again! Shame on you Google.

Comment: It's great to use this to turn off the new log when it stops working (happens too frequently).

Comment: With Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 (Beta 1, Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.9923731, built on April 12, 2023) the Experimental option now is *completely gone*. New Logcat is standard.

Comment: Thank you so much! I log by " (D|E)/" so I can filter out an abundance of Information logs, but I couldn't do that with the new logcat.

Comment: unfortunately, in the latest version of Android studio they completely removed this option :(

Comment: the experimental option is almost empty in new android version. this is frustrating