# How to return old Logs Style in Android Studio Dolphin

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just updated android studio to Android Studio Kotlin, but it appears that the logs have changed to a "newer" style. But I don't like that style and I want to return the old style, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get back logcat before dolphin version on android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775051/how-to-get-back-logcat-before-dolphin-version-on-android-studio)

Answer (score -1):

To manage wich version of logcat use :

Settings > Experimental > Don't check the Enable new Logcat tool window at the end.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJaYR.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJaYR.png)