# How to disable new LOGCAT in Android Studio Hedgehog?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am unable to find any option where I can disable the new logcat in Android Studio Hedgehog.
I want to use previous logcat.

Comment: This answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76766821/how-to-disable-new-logcat-in-android-studio-giraffe